# Modify how the generated views look like with Spring Roo without manually change each one post-creation?

Tags: templates, view, spring-roo

A simple question. How may I change how Spring Roo generates it's views so I do not need to change them post-creation? If I were to follow the [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html) it would look like [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/images/standardui.png), they however change the layout to [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/images/altui.png). From what I understand they have to change this manually after the view has been generated. What if I wanted the second view to be the base of all my generated views instead of the first one? Need I modify the source code or is there some simple way to override the generating code? Is it possible to set one base up for different projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roo uses Tiles (used for templating) and JSP tags for all of that stuff, and has built-in theme handling as well.  I believe in the tutorial for the Pizza shop, they are using a combination of modifing the Tiles templates AND a custom theme.

Once you modify the default theme, which if memory serves is just some CSS put in the a special folder under WEB-INF, and modify the Tiles templates, and new pages you have Roo auto-generate will inherit the new look-and-feel.

Comment: After reading your answer and re-reading the tutorial I now understand. "To achieve a higher level of customization you can change the default Tiles template (WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx) and adjust the JSP pages (WEB-INF/views/*.jspx)." Many thanks!